# Optical theorem for Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, feynman-diagrams, s-matrix-theory

I'm studying section 7.3 of Peskin and Schroeder. In the middle of page 232, the book says:

> For our present purposes, let us *define* $M$ by the Feynman rules for perturbation theory. This allows us to consider $M(s)$ as an analytic function of the complex variables $s=E_{cm}^2$, even though $S$-matrix elements are defined only for external particles with real momenta.

My question is: the $M$-matrix is given by something like $M(k_1,k_2\rightarrow p_1,p_2)$, it is not a function of a single variable. What does Peskin and Schroeder mean here?